# WordPress Date Picker not coming in Contact Form 7

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, datepicker, contact-form-7

i have creaed a form using Contact Form 7 , i have placed Date Field in that.
i used DatePicker Plugin to enable date picker on that field.

But i am getting a Fastclick console warning in that file. i tried to resolve that using function.php by using below code.

```
    if ( is_page('marketing') ){
        wp_register_script( 'fastclick','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fastclick/1.0.6/fastclick.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'fastclick' );
     }
```

After this JQuery issues are coming. 
    Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

how can i fix this .? i tried with different WordPress versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your plugin in the following line, jquery has the `jQuery` namespace in wordpress

```
(function($){
//the plugin js code
})(jQuery);
```